# How to add EventListener to a readonly input

Tags: javascript, jquery

After attaching an event listener to a readonly input, the `change` event doesn't fire if I programatically change the input's value.

like this

html:

```
 <input readonly="readonly" />
```

javascript:

```
$('input').on('change', function () {
    alert(this.val());
});

$('input').val('some value');
```

Comment: i will use jQuery change the input value.

Comment: how are you going to write text in `<input readonly="readonly" />`??

Comment: ^ This one states it the best.

Comment: The point being, I guess, that a readonly input doesn't change. Unless you change it. In which case you already know what the value is. This question definitely needs more context.

Comment: If you're going to to change the value programmatically, you have to call the listener in that context, for example: `$('input').trigger('change');`.

Comment: @Teemu yes,that's it,thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually trigger change event when you are changing the value of input through javascript.
See the demo:

```js
var i=0;
$('input').on('click',function(){
  i++;
  $(this).val(i);
  $(this).trigger('change');
});
$('input').on('change', function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input readonly="readonly" />
```